# drupal 7 states, set disabled unless any checkbox in a group is checked

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-forms

I currently have a form with a submit button that I would like to leave disabled unless any checkbox(es) in a group of them is checked. Currently, no matter what I do the button is not disabled. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$form['enrollments']['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Submit Change'),
      '#states' => array(
      'disabled' => array(
           'input:checked' => array('length' => 0),
      ),
 );
```

The checkboxes all share a shame name in array form like "students[12345]". So, if any one of those "students" checkboxes is checked the button should be enabled. However, given the code above the button is always enabled.

Comment: try using javascript / jquery

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue just come up with a Drupal 8 form using checkboxes and submit. The same should work for Drupal 7 forms, although the array definitions of `[]` may need to be updated to `array()`.

My checkboxes, of which I have 8, do not share an explicitly common name, so in order to accomplish this without adding 8 unique lines of `:input[name="..."]` I simply added a common data attribute to the checkbox items, which I could then target with the `#states` selector.

I also added a `#required => TRUE` to defend against the form somehow being submitted w/o any options selected. This causes the page to refresh and display an error highlighting the checkboxes, indicating a selection is required.

```
    $form['node_types'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkboxes',
      '#title' => $this->t('Select content types for report.'),
      '#title_display' => 'invisible',
      '#options' => $options,
      '#default_value' => array_keys($options),
      '#attributes' => [
        'data-type' => ['node-type-checkbox']
      ],
      '#required' => TRUE
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Download'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#states' => [
        'disabled' => [
          ':input[data-type="node-type-checkbox"]' => ['checked' => false],
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: You can also check if the input name starts with "node_types[" : ':input[name^="node_types["]'

Answer (score 0):

I think this link can solve your problem:
https://www.lullabot.com/articles/form-api-states

Also, you can use this if you want to show some thing upon visibility of checkbox:

```
'#states' => array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="nameofselectororfield"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
    '#states' => array(
      'disabled' => array(
       ':input[name="student12345"]' => array('checked' => FALSE),
      ),
    ),
  );
```